# Continuous notification from one Activity to another

Tags: android, android-activity, messaging

How can I have an activity B, which pops up and partially obscures a "parent" activity A, continuously send update info to A?

The normal mechanism, of course, would be to send an Intent back to A.  But this can only happen once, when calling finish().

I suppose another way would be to have a handler in A and let B post to the handler.  Getting the handler from A to B could be done through a "global" Application member.

Is there a better way?

EDIT: Using DialogFragment appears to be a good solution.  However there is a position issue with DialogFragment.  Please see my new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471032/position-dialogfragmet-relative-to-view

Comment: why an activity B and not a dialog to obscure your parent activity A?

Comment: Because I want the context to show.

Comment: "Is there a better way"? Fragments are probably much better suited for what you're trying to achieve here. You would have 2 fragments hosted inside the same activity and they could talk to each other via some interface that's passed in by the activity. This way, the lifecycle of both of them is intertwined as well and you don't have to worry about that aspect. Another solution is to use dialogs (as @JayeshElamgodil suggested) but in general, you probably shouldn't do this in activities.

Comment: As @Gordak noted, a point that you still seem to not be getting in your comments: activity A *might not be there at all*, and there's absolutely nothing you can do about this.  If your design depends on continuously communicating between activities, then your design is fundamentally broken.  Forget how to do it.  Fix your design.

Comment: Thanks - yes I realize that.  I'll have to check back at the documentation but I think priority is given to preserving underlying activities that are still visible.  Regardless, I'm re-looking at fragments - probably the better way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, an Activity always covers another Activity. At any point, Android could reclaim memory and destroy Activity A.

This means that you should manage your data differently. Either through your Application instance, if there is not much to share.

But you probably should consider another [storage mechanism](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). What kind of data do you want to pass to your Activity A ? And what do you mean by "partially obscures"?

**EDIT**

I would suggest that your DialogFragment keeps a reference to your Activity. Take a look at the [developer page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html). You can try to implement something like this:

In you Activity, when you would like to show your dialog:

```
void showDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyAlertDialogFragment.newInstance(
            R.string.alert_dialog_two_buttons_title);
    newFragment.setActivity(this);
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}
```

In your DialogFragment class, simply implement a setter method:

```
public static class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
  Activity activity;

  //rest of the code here

  public void setActivity(Activity a){
      this.activity = a;
  }
  private void notifyActivity(){
      int level = aMethod();
      activity.somethingHappened(level);
  }

}
```

Now, everytime you would like to call a method of your Activity, use the reference you passed previously.

I would also make an Interface, and make your Activity implement it. Like this, you are not dependent on one specific Activity, but it could be any UI component. Hope it helps.

Comment: I mean that B is mostly transparent except for a small area where the user interacts.  To be more precise, B is a special kind of popup widget.

Comment: Definitely go for a Dialog or Fragment. Even if your Activity B is transparent, you won't see your Activity A.

Comment: The question is about how to communicate.  Dialogs don't have any built-in communication mechanism except for finish().  Maybe fragments could use the parent Activity for communication but that's no different than my suggestion of using Application between two Activity(s).

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your problem... If you use a Dialog or a Fragment, simply communicate with your Activity through a direct reference to it.

Comment: A Dialog is an Activity.  There is no direct communication.  Same with fragments except that you can communicate "globally" through the parent activity.

Comment: DialogFragment might be what you need. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: DialogFragment would do what I want visually.  Do you know how the dialog can send notifications to the parent activity?

Comment: First of all, a `Dialog` is not an `Activity`. Secondly, any components can communicate with other components as long as you can pass a reference of the one component to the other. In case of a `Dialog`, you can always get a reference to the `Activity` that manages it by calling `getOwnerActivity()`. Once you have a reference to another component, you can just call methods on that component. You don't need to use `Intent`s to do this.

Comment: @DavidWasser thanks for the clarification.  So I could easily communicate back to the activity via getOwnerActivity().  I'm re-looking at fragments since that appears to be a better way to go.  With fragments, I hope I can encapsulate the communications into an interface, so that the fragment doesn't have to have any specific syntactically attachment to the activity.

Comment: I checked this as the correct solution because I think it is correct to use DialogFragment.  However, there are a number of residual issues.  I've made a new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471032/position-dialogfragmet-relative-to-view